# Codename one customizing capturing image from camera

Tags: codenameone

First of I would like to thank the codename one team for the support to get me through some of the tough tasks I have faced.  Now that I have solid app that I am ready to submit to the app store, I would like to know bit more detail or any examples of how the capturing photo can be cropped.
If I want to capture an photo using the camera, I want to crop it to desired width and height of the photo.  Is there any example to crop the image and show the cropping area while taking picture?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

You can use `Image newImage = myImage.fill(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);` this will retain aspect ratio and crop the redundant areas.